# NullReference Exception in date Conversion

Tags: c#

I am working on `Hijri` to `Gregorian` conversion of date. However, I get this `NullReferenceException`error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
pprivate HttpContext cur;

    private const int startGreg=1900;
    private const int endGreg=2100;
    private string[] allFormats={"yyyy/MM/dd","yyyy/M/d",
        "dd/MM/yyyy","d/M/yyyy",
        "dd/M/yyyy","d/MM/yyyy","yyyy-MM-dd",
        "yyyy-M-d","dd-MM-yyyy","d-M-yyyy",
        "dd-M-yyyy","d-MM-yyyy","yyyy MM dd",
        "yyyy M d","dd MM yyyy","d M yyyy",
        "dd M yyyy","d MM yyyy"};
    private CultureInfo arCul;
    private CultureInfo enCul;
    private HijriCalendar h;
    private GregorianCalendar g;

    public void Dates()
    {
        cur = HttpContext.Current;


        arCul=new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
        enCul=new CultureInfo("en-US");

        h=new  HijriCalendar();
        g=new GregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendarTypes.USEnglish);

        arCul.DateTimeFormat.Calendar=h;

    }

    public string HijriToGreg(string hijri)
    {

        if (hijri.Length<=0)
        {

            cur.Trace.Warn("HijriToGreg :Date String is Empty");
            return "";
        }
        try
        {

            DateTime tempDate=DateTime.ParseExact(hijri,allFormats,
               arCul.DateTimeFormat,DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
            return tempDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd",enCul.DateTimeFormat);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            cur.Trace.Warn("HijriToGreg :"+"\n"+ex.ToString());
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include some code

Comment: Post the code exists in your `try` block

Comment: We can't help you until we find where and how your all objects were initiated. `allformats`, `arcul`, `encul`

Comment: I have added the code... is that helpful Shaharyar?

Comment: Alright people... I found it.. i was actually initializing the variable CUR outside the method/function. I realized it later..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WhatEver cur = new WhatEver();
```

Answer (score 1):

That means that *somewhere* you are accessing a field, property or method on a reference-type variable that is `null` (or accessing `.Value` on `Nullable<T>` struct). We can't tell you where, but `ex.StackTrace` can, as can adding a break-point and stepping through the code near where it errors, looking at the variables etc for the rogue `null` (or the *correct* `null` with a missing `null`-check)

Answer (score 0):

This means you are using an object without initialing it. use new keyword to initialize  it.